# ¿Cómo activar/desactivar estas etiquetas de nombres de parámetros que me muestra el IDE Netbeans en el código?

Tags: java, ide, apache-netbeans

Según lo que he observado aparecen en las variables, y a la hora de identar código ocupan espacio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No responde al IDE NetBeans, pero para el que necesita en Eclipse, esa opción se encuentra en Window>Preferences>Java>Editor>Code Minings y se activa/desactiva con el checkbox que dice "Show method parameter names"

Comment: @JFrame Gracias estimado, gracias a eso pude encontrarlo en Netbeans

Answer (score 1):

Para activarlo o desactivarlo, en el menú principal:
*View* > *Show Inline Hints*